# How to reduce time of PeriodicWorkManager in WorkManager

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

In `PeriodicTimeRequest` minimum periodic time is 15 minute. I want to reduce it from 15 min to less than 15 minute.How can i do that?

Comment: You can't. If you could then they would not say 15 minutes is the minimum. I don't know what you want to do but probably WorkManager is not right for your purpose and should find some other way of doing it.

Comment: @Alan What API i should use for reducing a time period of android pie less than 15 minutes . I am also implementaing JobScheduler API but not working. If you have any solution please tell me

Comment: You are not giving not enough info on the broader problem you are trying to solve and asking me to solve it. If you want good answers then you would first need to ask good questions. All I can say is that if you need to do periodic work that repeats in less than 15 minutes then WorkManager or JobScheduler is not to right approach. You can try using AlarmManager but it does not work when the device is in doze mode. It all depends on what broader problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @ Alan Currently i am working on one Android Application if any change is happen on server side then immediate notification show if Android Application is not running

Comment: Please accept my answer. Look at the link and search for more information if needed. Unless you still have question about work manager's minimum scheduling period you should not be asking new qeustions that is off topic here.

Comment: @Alan Thankyou for giving a answer I added Evernote WorkJob ApI in my project

Answer (score 8):

We have a hack to reduce the 15mins time to run periodically. But you can't use PeriodicWorkRequest. Create OneTimeWorkRequest with initial delay and call self at the end of the work inside the worker. if required create 
 the backgroundExecutor.execute {} and call from inside to make asynchronous calling. Means the worker which called self will not be terminated or onStopped() will not be called.

ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE | KEEP may be required depends on your need.

Answer (score 8):

A simple answer is **No**, You cannot reduce the time to less than MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS which is hardcoded to 15 Minutes.

However, you can test PeriodicWorkRequest sooner than MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS which is 15 minutes.

For this, you need `WorkManagerTestInitHelper` available in `androidx.work.testing`.

First of all add the following dependency in the build.gradle file for your app or module:

```
//Current stable release is 2.3.4
androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:2.3.4
```

Next, you need to use `setPeriodDelayMet` method available with `TestDriver` which can be used to indicate that an interval is complete and executes PeriodicWorkRequest sooner than MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS (15 minutes).
Sample code:

```
@Test
public void testPeriodicWork(Context context) throws Exception {
    // Setup input data
    Data input = new Data.Builder().put(KEY_1, 1).put(KEY_2, 2).build();

    // Create periodic work request
    PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 15,  TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                       .setInputData(input)
                                       .build();
    // Enqueue periodic request
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(WORKER_TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, request);

    // Initialize testDriver
    TestDriver testDriver = WorkManagerTestInitHelper.getTestDriver();

    // Tells the testing framework the period delay is met, this will execute your code in doWork() in MyWorker class
    testDriver.setPeriodDelayMet(request.getId());

}
```

You can find more information about testing PeriodicWorkRequest at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/integration-testing#periodic-work

Learn more about testing WorkManager at https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/WorkManagerTestInitHelper and https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/TestDriver

Answer (score 3):

No, You cannot reduce the time to less than `PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS` which is **15 Minutes**
That's a system limitation because of the battery saving, there is no hack.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution: https://ariefbayu.xyz/execute-periodic-process-under-15-minutes-cycle-using-workmanager-564c3ade94c4

```
public Result doWork() {

    try {
        Log.d("PWLOG", "Let me sleep a moment...");
        Thread.sleep(60000 * 5);//5 minutes cycle
        doTheActualProcessingWork();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.d("PWLOG", "Thread sleep failed...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Result.success();
}
```

It seems to work in a correct way

Answer (score 1):

If interval time under 15 minutes.I create multiple tasks,like that:

```
if (PublicStaticData.systemSet.rescueuploadinterval <= 15) {
          WorkManager.getInstance(this).cancelAllWorkByTag("uploadLocationWork")
          val tasks = 15 / PublicStaticData.systemSet.rescueuploadinterval
          for (taskNo in 0 until tasks) {
            val uploadLocationWork = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UploadLocationWork>(
                PublicStaticData.systemSet.rescueuploadinterval.toLong(), TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addTag("uploadLocationWork")
                .setInitialDelay((PublicStaticData.systemSet.rescueuploadinterval * taskNo).toLong(), TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build()
            WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(uploadLocationWork)
            Log.e("jjj", "任务${taskNo}延迟${PublicStaticData.systemSet.rescueuploadinterval * taskNo}开始")
          }
        } else {
          // 超过15分钟，正常用就行
          WorkManager.getInstance(this).cancelAllWorkByTag("uploadLocationWork")
          val uploadLocationWork = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UploadLocationWork>(
              PublicStaticData.systemSet.rescueuploadinterval.toLong(), TimeUnit.MINUTES)
              .addTag("uploadLocationWork")
              .setInitialDelay(PublicStaticData.systemSet.rescueuploadinterval.toLong(), TimeUnit.MINUTES)
              .build()
          WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(uploadLocationWork)
        }
```

There is an acceptable deviation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the minimum time of 15 minutes. If it can be changed to less than that then it would not be called minimum.
Depending on your need try using Alarm Manager or FCM. 
Refer to the following link for more details: https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/regular_updates

Comment: Hii @Alan after some time i have do research lots of time and found evernote-android/job https://github.com/evernote/android-job , it's working fine some device which greater than API level 21(MarshMallow) but in MI devices not working

Comment: @ShubhanshuSingh Thanks for sharing your findings. I would like to also note that scheduling work to wake up the device frequently may eat up lot of battery and result in poor user experience. I would advise to really make sure that this is only used when absolutely needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to workaround this with this approach:

```
companion object {
    private const val NOTIFICATION_REPEAT_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES = 15L
    private const val NOTIFICATION_FLEX_TIME_IN_MINUTES = 14L
}
    
    val notificationRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>(
                    NOTIFICATION_REPEAT_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES , TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                    NOTIFICATION_FLEX_TIME_IN_MINUTES , TimeUnit.MINUTES
                )
                    .addTag(NOTIFICATION_TAG)
                    .build()
    
                WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext()).enqueue(notificationRequest)
```

So what happens here is that the difference between `NOTIFICATION_REPEAT_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES` and `NOTIFICATION_FLEX_TIME_IN_MINUTES` is only `1` (so less than the minimum 15 minutes for `minimum repeat interval`).
The docs are here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#flexible_run_intervals
However I suggest to only use this if you're indeed flexible. For me it was useful for testing, because I didn't want to wait 15 minutes everytime.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot reduce time to less than 15 minutes, as you can see in the picture, it's set default to 15 Minutes
[image: Screenshot of minimum time]