# Could not instantiate Worker

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, mobile-development

I am making an app that communicates with a PC via Bluetooth. Right now I am working on a worker class entitled BluetoothCommWorker that is contained within my class for Connect PC's entitled ConnectedPC. I created the worker and enqueued it according to the Android documentation. However, when I try to enqueue it, I get the output and error:

```
W/WM-WorkSpec: Interval duration lesser than minimum allowed value; Changed to 900000
E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate com.example.app.ConnectedPC$BluetoothCommWorker
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.app.ConnectedPC$BluetoothCommWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2170)
        at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:244)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:136)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Could not create Worker com.example.app.ConnectedPC$BluetoothCommWorker
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.SystemClock;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.work.Constraints;
import androidx.work.Data;
import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ConnectedPC {
    private final BluetoothDevice BLUETOOTH_DEVICE;
    private boolean isActivePC;
    private PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest;

    public ConnectedPC(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
        this.BLUETOOTH_DEVICE = bluetoothDevice;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return BLUETOOTH_DEVICE.getName();
    }

    public boolean isActivePC() {
        return isActivePC;
    }

    public void setActivePC(boolean activeDevice) {
        isActivePC = activeDevice;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return BLUETOOTH_DEVICE.getAddress();
    }

    public void initWork(Context context) {
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().build();

        periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                BluetoothCommWorker.class,
                5,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
        ).setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInitialDelay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addTag(String.format("%s: BluetoothCommWorker", BLUETOOTH_DEVICE.getName()))
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
    }

    public class BluetoothCommWorker extends Worker {

        public BluetoothCommWorker(@NonNull Context context,
                                   @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
            super(context, workerParams);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Result doWork() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE.getName() + ": " + i);
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return Result.failure();
            }

            return Result.retry();
        }
    }
}
```

The doWork function just contains a dummy for-loop because I am wanting to get the worker code working first before I actually work on the work code. Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Minimum interval for periodic work is 15 minutes (900 seconds, 900000 milliseconds) - as indicated in the error output. You should replace the units and amount like this:

```
        periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            BluetoothCommWorker.class,
            15,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES
        )
```

There are other methods if you need shorter intervals:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

edit: there are tricks to run work with shorter intervals using one-time workers re-scheduling themselves

[How to decrease time period of Workmanager Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811294/how-to-decrease-time-period-of-workmanager-android)

Also you probably should consider foreground service to notify users they have a process running tasks with minuscule interval + some means to stop the task i.e. "stop" button or redirection to your application where the user can stop the task:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services